# ESLint rule to allow only either default or named exports per file

Tags: javascript, eslint

I wish to have a following ESLint rule:

A js file can have either one default export, or as many named exports as possible. But not both. So having one default export + named exports should result in an eslint warning. Is this possible with eslint currently? If not, would it be easy to make a rule like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for [prefer-default-export](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/src/rules/prefer-default-export.js), it looks like it may well be as simple as forking that rule and changing

```
'Program:exit': function() {
  if (specifierExportCount === 1 && !hasDefaultExport && !hasStarExport) {
    context.report(namedExportNode, 'Prefer default export.')
  }
},
```

to

```
'Program:exit': function() {
  if ((specifierExportCount >= 1 || hasStarExport) && hasDefaultExport) {
    context.report(namedExportNode, 'Do not use both named exports and a default export')
  }
},
```

`specifierExportCount` in that rule module counts the number of named exports.